# Vite import all scss files in a directory

Tags: javascript, laravel, vite

I'm planning to migrate from Webpack to Vite in a Laravel project, but I'm facing an issue when converting one specific line.

In my Webpack configuration, I was able to import all the `.scss` files within a directory using this line:

```
@import "./commons/**/*.scss"
```

However, I haven't found a way to achieve the same with Vite configuration.

So, I'm wondering if there's a way to import all the SCSS files within a directory using a single import statement in Vite or if I should consider creating a pre-script JS to import all the SCSS files within the directory, and then import that generated file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in this issue https://github.com/vitejs/vite/pull/6371#issuecomment-1013881428 Vite will not support this kind of imports natively, so you need to use a plugin.

You can use this one: https://github.com/cmalven/vite-plugin-sass-glob-import